# Tint color is not working for image in Xamarin Forms in iOS?

Tags: ios, image, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, tintcolor

I'm working on Embedded Images Tint color in xamarin forms using with [this](https://github.com/shrutinambiar/xamarin-forms-tinted-image/tree/master/demo/Demo.CrossPlatformTintedImage) nuget package, working fine in android but not in iOS.
As per my search I used rendering mode to AlwaysTemplate but in my scenario I'm unable to use rendering mode.
what I'm doing is using the image references from solution file not from iOS assets.

Below is my code snippet.

```
 <controls:TintedImage
           x:Name="ColorChange"
           Aspect="AspectFit"
           HeightRequest="17"
           Source="{local:ImageResource AppName.Images.dot.png}"
           TintColor="{StaticResource PlaceholderColor}"
           VerticalOptions="Center"
           WidthRequest="17" />
```

I want to change TintColor if an image without rendering image for iOS in xamarin forms.

---

Comment: that package it's really outdated, even the owner have archived it. I don't know if you can tint a `png` image, maybe try with svg images.

Comment: Thanks! is it possible to change tint color of embedded images?

Comment: Any alternate libraries??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom renderer of `Image` to change the tint color and `UIImageRenderingMode`.

In Xamarin.forms:

```
public class myImage : Image
{

}
```

In iOS project:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(myImage), typeof(myImageRenderer))]
namespace WorkingWithImages.iOS
{
    public class myImageRenderer : ImageRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Image> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            Control.TintColor = UIColor.Red;

        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (Control.Image != null)
            {
                UIImage image = Control.Image;

                image = image.ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate);

                Control.Image = image;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Jack Hua, I'm using same code Image rendered mode has changed but still image tint color is not changing.
static void showWarning(myImage tintedImage, bool show)
     {
          if (show)
    {
     if (tintedImage.TintColor != Color.Gray)
     {
      tintedImage.Source ="dot.png";
      tintedImage.TintColor = Color.Gray;
     }
    }
    else
    {
     if (tintedImage.TintColor != Color.Green)
     {
      tintedImage.Source = "check_circle.png";
      tintedImage.TintColor = Color.Green;
     }
    }
   }

Comment: Did you add a breakpoint there to see if the codes has executed?

Comment: Yes it's executed, Image source has changed but Tintcolor not changed

Comment: Will the tintcolor change under AlwaysTemplate? Can you try other rendering mode?

Comment: Hua Thanks it's working. Minor change to append tint color



' if (Control.Image != null)
            {
                Control.Image = Control.Image.ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate);
                Control.TintColor = ((myImage)Element).TintColor.ToUIColor();
            }'